# Decipher DbContext components

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

If `public UsersContext()` is the constructor of the `DbContext`, why is it inheriting from the OfficeData database? How does the inheritance work? Since a database cannot be a base class. 
It's not even a class.

I can understand that the UsersContext is inheriting from the built-in DbContext base class.

```
public class UsersContext : DbContext
{
    public UsersContext(): base("OfficeData")
    {
    }

    //contains this model
    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It is not inheriting from OfficeData, it is simply passing a string to the constructor of the superclass.

Comment: So it's passing "OfficeData" to a constructor in the DbContext base class?

Comment: Did you just get a snip of code and go from there? The questions you're asking are usually the first ones answered in any EF introduction.

Comment: See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679467(v=vs.113).aspx) for details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's definitely not "inheriting" anything from `"OfficeData"`. And `"OfficeData"` isn't a database, it's a string. That's it. In this context, it's a string telling the base class constructor which connection string in the Web/App.config to use when it connects to the database. It has nothing to do with inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

That is name of connection string in config file.